# Why can't I set the buffer and offload on a wireless card?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

To access the settings I mentioned on a Windows system, right-click a network adapter, then "properties", then "configure", then "advanced".

For a wired NIC, many of them have settings for TX/RX buffer, TCP/large checksum offload, Jumbo frame... etc. But on a wireless card there's **only** some setting about wireless, none of them have such settings as seen on wired card, does this mean that those features are not available for any wireless card?

Comment: If it's a USB card, those kinds of features that are based on memory-mapping I/O buffers won't apply since you USB isn't a shared memory bus.

Comment: David Schwartz: No, all refers to onboard/PCI type.

Comment: Maybe because of your driver. What card is? do you mean any wifi card? Which Windows version? Because I use W10 and I have some special options for the internal wifi card like "Transmit buffers" clicking on "device manager", right click, "properties", "advanced features".

Comment: It would definitely help to know what specific Wifi hardware we are talking about.

Comment: I never see any wireless driver can set these, if you really want a example, both card on Panasonic CF-U1 and ASUS M81C don't have.